# iOS - UIActivityIndicator not animating or hiding while loading a webpage

Tags: xcode, ios5, uiactivityindicatorview, iphone-4

I know this has been discussed several times already but can't figure out why my activity indicator is not working.

What I want: UIActivityIndicator is visible and starts animating while a webpage is loading and hides automatically when the load is finished.

What I have: UIActivityIndicator is not hiding or animating, is shown fixed in the centre of my view.

Note: The outlet `indicator` is connected to the IB object in IB (see screenshot).

H FILE:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AbschlagViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *abschlagWebView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator;

@end
```

M FILE:

```
@synthesize abschlagWebView, indicator;

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    indicator.hidden = FALSE;
    [indicator startAnimating];
}


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    indicator.hidden = TRUE;
    [indicator stopAnimating];
}
```

IB Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Just checking; have you set the delegate for the UIWebView instance, so that `webViewDidStartLoad` and `webViewDidFinishLoad` are called?

Comment: :-) No I did not. Now it's working, thanks Peter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `delegate` for the `UIWebView` instance, so that `webViewDidStartLoad` and `webViewDidFinishLoad` methods are called?